# I want to make div background image responsive

Tags: html, css

This is my div tag background image code.

```
<div class="text-center paira-gap-2 paira-gap-1 position-r  parallax parallax-1527413728902" style="background: url(&quot;//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0611/5003/6139/files/Home2_1659f2cd-aa5a-4d18-9a93-b5955c1ec056.png?v=1648657681&quot;) 50% 8px no-repeat fixed; height: 900px;">
```

If someone have solution let me know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and set it to `cover` to span the entire `div`. In addition, I recommend, placing the background to the center:

```css
div {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center paira-gap-2 paira-gap-1 position-r  parallax parallax-1527413728902" style="background-url: url(&quot;//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0611/5003/6139/files/Home2_1659f2cd-aa5a-4d18-9a93-b5955c1ec056.png?v=1648657681&quot;) background-size: cover; background-position: center; height: 900px;">
```